# How do I add a logo to my html website? Only showing a little icon instead of the entire pic

Tags: html, image, broken-image

Trying to add the 4 dry out logo to this html template. Can anyone correct what I did wrong? It shows this on the site:
[image: 4 dry out logo]

This is a very small section of the code where I have the image placed in the body.

```
<body>
    <!-- Loader -->
    <div id="loader-wrapper">
        <div id="loader"></div>
        <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
        <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container-fluid tm-main">
        <div class="row tm-main-row">

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div id="tmSideBar" class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 sidebar">

                <button id="tmMainNavToggle" class="menu-icon">&#9776;</button>

                <div class="inner">
                    <nav id="tmMainNav" class="tm-main-nav">
                        <ul>
     <!--ERROR IMG -->      <img data-image="4 Dry Out Logo.jpg" alt="4 Dry Out Logo">
                            <li>
```

Comment: should that be `src` instead of `data-image`?

Comment: Please don't edit your title to include "Solved" - the system knows that it's solved because you awarded a green check mark to one of the answers. Thanks!

Comment: My bad! Noob here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <img data-image="4DryOutLogo.jpg" alt="4 Dry Out Logo">
```

First you need to consider renaming the image and remove white space from the name.

Second ,  you have to use the code as below

```
    <img src = "../yourimagename.jpg">
```

Finally ,
You have to make sure that your image exist with in the server path.
I suggest you to first open the image via url link , once its open copy paste that url into the src code .

Good luck

Comment: I had tried src before but it hadn't worked because I had no "img/" before the file name. ah! thanks so much.

Comment: your welcome glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is other code acting on your `img` tag, you need to use the `src` attribute to specify an image URL. Spaces in the image name could also be causing an issue.

You'll want to open up your web browser's developer tools and see if you can see where the image is requested in the *network* tab. If the URL is returning a 404 error, you know that there is an issue with your image's path. If the request for the image isn't being made at all, then there is an issue with your `img` tag or the code that is supposed to cause the request for the image to be sent.